# How to deal with long/permanent open handles in JDBI?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

The `JDBI` library documentation outlines various usages of handles and SQL Objects, but it seems to be missing a use case that I cannot imagine is specific to my current code:

I want to open a connection to the database, and then just keep that connection open until the end of my application runtime (which is measured in days).

I do not want to incur the performance cost in having to reopen the connection whenever I need it, so I don't want to manually call `withHandle`/`withExtension` or make use of the `onDemand` functionality.

I could simply open a handle and store it (I am not concerned with the potential of resource leakage, as the handle would be stored in a CDI managed `Singleton`), but then what happens if the database or the connection to it goes away ?

I imagine at some point I will need to deal with refreshing the handle after a database disconnect, as that kind of thing is bound to eventually happen, and should not require my application to restart, but where would be the appropriate point for handling that ?

Comment: Are you using a connection pool already? That can manage open connections for you. I use Hikari with jdbi. I get my jdbi handles from the pool. It also lets me configure the minimum number of pool connections, etc. including creating new connections for me, if some are dropped for whatever (recoverable) reason.